# how can i find changes in a specific column and get the old value

Tags: sql-server

Good morning all

I would appreciate any help you can give me in this subject

I have a table that grows in time with the same Id1
but some time Id2 change , like a historic of a park.

I would like to find the best way with a query to retrieve
the rows where id2 changes and time

example if table contents are

```
Id1  Id2      time
1      1      10:00
1      1      10:30
1      2      10:40
1      2      10:45
1      2      11:00
1      3      11:45
1      3      12:45
```

query output would be

```
Id1  oldId2  newId2     time
1      1       2       10:40
1      2       3        11:45
```

i have done with a stored procedure, but I was wondering of there is a faster/cleaner way to get this

thanks in advance

Comment: What is wrong with your stored procedure?    If it is slow, post the code so we can debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by Ranking functions..

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (Id1 INT,Id2 INT, timeS TIME  )

INSERT INTO #TAB        
SELECT 1 AS Id1 , 1 Id2, '10:00' AS timeS
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, '10:30'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, '10:40'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, '10:45'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, '11:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, '11:45'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, '12:45'
```

Now do select with ROW_NUMBER and CTE for retrieving previous/next row values.

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNO
        ,ID1
        ,ID2
        ,timeS
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY TIMES) AS SNO
            ,*
        FROM #TAB
        ) A
    WHERE SNO = 1
    )
SELECT C1.Id1
    ,C1.Id2 AS OLD_ID2
    ,C2.Id2 AS NEW_ID2
    ,C2.timeS
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO + 1 = C2.RNO
WHERE C2.Id1 IS NOT NULL
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+---------+---------+------------------+
| Id1 | OLD_ID2 | NEW_ID2 |      timeS       |
+-----+---------+---------+------------------+
|   1 |       1 |       2 | 10:40:00.0000000 |
|   1 |       2 |       3 | 11:45:00.0000000 |
+-----+---------+---------+------------------+
```

**Note:** If you want to get Previous/Next Row values into current row, you can use LEAD LAG functions. But they support only in SQL Server 2012+.
The above Left Join with CTE will work for lower versions too.

Comment: well, it was very close whati wanted

Comment: i have done some changes and here it is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Id1 int, Id2 int, [time] time)
    insert into @t
        select 1, 1, '10:00' union
        select 1, 1, '10:30' union
        select 1, 2, '10:40' union
        select 1, 2, '10:45' union
        select 1, 2, '11:00' union
        select 1, 3, '11:45' union
        select 1, 3, '12:45' 

select Id1, oldId = (select top 1 id2 from @t where Id1=t.Id1 and  Id2 < t.Id2 order by id2, time desc), newId = id2, time = min(time)
from @t t
where id2 > 1
group by Id1, id2
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done some changes to the code from Shakeer Mirza.
the pratical problem that originated the question in the first place is:
i have a table that represents the history of an equipment. Being machine internal id(Num_TPA).
Each time there is a malfunction, the machine is replaced by another it keeps the same Num_TPA but Serial_number changes
i needed to know  what is the historic on internal_id->Num_TPA . the new and the old serial_number , and the date of replacement

and this is what it came out.

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNO
        ,[Num_TPA]
        ,[Serial_number]
        ,[Time]
        ,a.SNO
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Num_TPA] 
        ORDER BY [Data_Hora_Ficheiro]) AS SNO
            ,*
        FROM tab_values
        ) A
    WHERE SNO > 1
    )
SELECT C1.[Num_TPA]
    ,C1.[Serial_number] AS OLD_ID2
    ,C2.[Serial_number] AS NEW_ID2
    ,C2.[Data_Hora_Ficheiro]
    ,c2.SNO
    ,c2.RNO
FROM tab_values C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON (
        C1.[Num_TPA] = C2.[Num_TPA]
        AND c1.[Serial_number] != c2.[Serial_number]
        AND C2.[Time] > c1.TIME
        )
WHERE C2.[Num_TPA] IS NOT NULL
    AND SNO = 2

UNION

SELECT C1.[Num_TPA]
    ,C1.[Serial_number] AS OLD_ID2
    ,C2.[Serial_number] AS NEW_ID2
    ,C2.[Data_Hora_Ficheiro]
    ,c2.SNO
    ,c2.RNO
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON (
        C1.SNO + 1 = C2.SNO
        AND C1.[Num_TPA] = C2.[Num_TPA]
        )
WHERE C2.[Num_TPA] IS NOT NULL
    AND C2.SNO > 2
```